# video shader 300 frames to make 1000 frames

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, image

I have the below video shader which is composed of an image texture node to which I uploaded this video.

It is 300 frames long and I would like to repeat it for 1000 frames.  How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: No.  I don't think so.  The image I am using is already a video of 300 frames.  Tired cyclic but with no result and it does not seem that I can upload the same video with a different numeric sequence in one image texture node.

Comment: Works great, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9A0q.gif Animated the color of the default cube, rendered 3 frames and load them back in (using Images as Planes add-on to speed up the process). Loops the sequence as expected...